# 「Jenkinsの拡張をこれからはじめて実施したいと考えています。 」は範囲が広すぎる？

Tags: 討議, クローズ理由

[Jenkinsの拡張をこれからはじめて実施したいと考えています。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/38993/754) は、今現在「範囲が広すぎる」としてクローズされています。個人的には、これはいい質問なのではないか、と思っています。というのも、これから Jenkins の機能拡張を行おうと思うと、たしかにそれを簡単に行うための方法はでてこないからです。はじめて拡張を行う、ということで、たぶん質問者さんが知りたいと思っているのは、「ざっくりどんな拡張方法があるのか、それぞれでどういう作業を行うことになるのか」なのかなと思っていて、そうすると回答は可能そうです。

「範囲が広すぎる」クローズは、本質的に長々とした回答出ない限り回答できないような（もしくは、抽象度を上げてまとめたところで、実際の質問者の抱えているであろう問題は解決しないような）質問に対して行うべきなのではないかと考えています。とすると、この質問はオープンでもいいのではないかと思ったりもします。

jenkins ということで、分野に関する知見が必要で汎化した結論はでないかもしれませんが、ふと気になったので質問しています。

Comment: ベストプラクティスはないにしろワークフローを教えてください。という点でどこの範囲が広すぎると感じたのか分からないですね。再オープンでもいいのでは？ほか、気になる点と言えば言及はされていませんが環境が書かれていないくらいですかね。

Answer (score 5):

現時点ではそれなりの品質の回答が得られるレベルでないので、積極的に「クローズは誤りである」とは感じません。(すでに再オープンされてしまいましたが)

コメントつけましたが、

### やりたいことが不明確

「拡張」というのが具体的に何かわからず、単に既存のプラグインを導入すれば良いだけの話かもしれない。既存のプラグインでは不可能なことが明確なのだとすると、そもそもプラグインでは解決不可能かもしれない。

### 質問者の知識が不明確

Jenkins/HudsonとJavaについてどれだけの知識があるか不明なので、どこから説明が必要なのかわからない。

と言う状況では、質問者が必要とするレベルの回答をするにはまぐれ当たりに期待するしかありません。

また、ある程度のレベルを勝手に想像したとしても、回答はそれなりの長さになるでしょう。情報が全く無いような分野ならともかく、「Jenkins プラグイン 開発」とかで検索するだけでそれなりの解説が見つかるのですから、回答出来る人がいたとしても改めてここに解説記事を投稿するようなモチベーションにはなかなか繋がらないと思います。

そうすると、全く回答が集まらないか、リンクのみとか断片的とかそのような品質の低い回答があつまるか、どちらにせよあまりいい結果にはならないと思います。

---

後者の話は「ワークフローを教えてください」という質問一般に該当します。

ヘルプには「回答が本一冊」というのが出てきますが、そこまで行かなくとも雑誌記事一本とか、そこそこの長さのブログ記事にできてしまうような分量になり、それが質問を前提とせずに書けてしまうのであれば、それは質問内容が具体的でないということだと思います。

そのような質問であっても十分な品質の回答が得られるのであればよいですが、それに期待するのは難しいですし、ポインタだけとかデッド/劣化コピーのような回答を招くことになります。

クローズするかどうかは別問題として、好ましい質問ではないでしょう。

Comment: その後の顛末を見ていましたが、たしかに質問者さんの知りたかったことは、「プラグインの作り方」である様子ですね。その意味では、最初の質問設定である、「Jenkins の拡張方法一般についてのワークフロー」は確かに広すぎる。。